# pass css as component parameter

Tags: css, vue.js

I want to create a component with some CSS parameters. I know I'm not able to do something like this

```
<template>
  <div id="textContainer">
    {{ content }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    content: String,
    textAlign: String
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
#textContainer {
  text-align: {{textAlign}}; // this won't work
}
</style>
```

but I thought about creating a component that deals with the css parameters in the HTML code like this example

```
<template>
  <div id="textContainer" :style="'text-align: {{textAlign}}'">
    this should be right aligned
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    textAlign: String
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
#textContainer {
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

and consume it with

```
<MyComponent textAlign="right" />
```

I don't know if this won't work or my syntax is wrong. I provide a working example

https://codesandbox.io/s/my002w6oqy

and would like to know if there is a way to create components with dynamic css parameters. Otherwise I would have to create components which only differ in their css style.

Comment: I would prefer passing CSS classes instead of styles.  What will happen if you want to change the style in future? You can name classes as themes preferable e.g. theme_a, theme_b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can use the object syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1):

```
<template>
  <div id="textContainer" :style="{ textAlign }">
    this should be right aligned
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    textAlign: String
  }
};
</script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wnpl6zvnlw

Comment: thanks for your help. Your example works fine but I don't get why it works. How does `textAlign` match to `text-align`?

Comment: Vue convert camel case `textAlign` to kebab-case `text-align` during the compiling process. And also notice `{ textAlign }` is short for `{ textAlign: textAlign }` and then camel case to kebab-case `{ 'text-align': textAlign }`.